# Coloring nodes based on a distribution of values using Networkx

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a code to represent a network of nodes using Networkx:

I create the nodes in such a way that each node (key) is associated to a list of values ​​that oscillate between 100 and 0 (representing percentages):

```
import networkx as nx
nodes = {
    "1": [100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    "2": [0,25,0,25,25,25,0,0],
    "3": [0.050,0,30,0,20,0],
    "4": [0.0,0,100,0,0,0,0],
    "5": [0,0,0,0 , 10,10,0,80],
    "6": [0,0,0,0,0,100,0,0],
    "7": [0,0,0,0,70,30,0 ],
    "8": [0.0,0,0,0,0,0,100]
}
```

I generate the axes (interactions):

```
pairs = [("1", "2"), ("3", "4"), ("5", "6"), ("7", "8")]
edges = combinations(nodes, 2)
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(nodes)
g.add_edges_from(pairs)
```

So far, I have managed to draw simple networks but I would like to be able to represent each node (from 1 to 8) with a different color (or combination of colours) according to its distribution of values.

So, if a node has 100 in a value in the list its color would be plain but, on the contrary, if the distribution of values is other [e.g. [25,25,25,25,0,0,0,0] the colour of the node would be either a proportional mixure of colours or a combination of them (according to the distribution of values).

For example, 100 in the first value in the list may correspond to plain blue, 100 in the second value of the list plain green, 100 in the third yellow, 100 in the fourth pink, and so on.

The complicated thing is to represent the nodes for mixtures of colors. For example, let's imagine that nodes ["1"] corresponds to the following list [25,25,25,25,0,0,0,0]. How could I make the node appear represented by a fair mix of these colors ?, or how to make each node appear colored with the percentage of each color according to its own distribution of values?

Comment: So, are your list-contents representative of a set of scores, from zero to 100 in each dimension? How do you intend to map a colourspace onto this (by count) 8-dimensional vector? i.e. If you had 3-dimensions, that'd be easy, as you could just map [r,g,b] onto [s1,s2,s3]. Or are you saying that you're going to start with palette of 8 colours, in which case, how do you intend to mix them? Is it the case that any final post mix can be achieved by more than one unique combination of source-values? You can model 4-dimensions using cmyk (or rgbs) but I think that's as far as it goes, practically.

Comment: You could find a way to reduce the 8-dimentions into 4-dimentions and use the [CMYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) color model.

Comment: Yeah. 8 values representing each one one specific plain colour. I was thinking in two options, either represent the final colour-result mixing proportionally the 3 highest values in the list, or representing each node with partitions according with its distribution of values in the list. The idea is to capture these different distributions of values with a different combination of colours.

Comment: Are there any relations between these 8 values?

Comment: Each value in the list is a percentage. So the higher a value the lower the others. But there is no further relationship.